# Pinned icons not showing original app's icon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate. After installing Paragon Partition Manager 10 Personal, 3 of the 6 application icons in the taskbar are not rendering properly. Generic file icons is being rendered there instead of original app's icon. Googleing about the problem shows that this is a known issue and one solution is to change the size of the taskbar icons to small, then revert back to large (I use large by default). But this solution doesn't work for my case. I tried restarting the PC which doesn't work either.

Is there any other solution for the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the taskbar shortcut while holding the Shift key and select Properties.
Change the icon as you would for any other desktop shortcut.

You need to reboot for the change to take effect.
Or alternatively to booting, just kill explorer.exe from the Task Manager, then re-run it from the menu File -> New task.

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting the icon cache as described in [this](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2422299) solved the problem.